# how to convert a git format-patch patch to a traditional patch

Tags: git

How do I convert a git format-patch output to a traditional patch?

Git format-patch returns a patch like:

```
git format-patch -1  1d962ecf1e8d42c09abac2f715239a592c9415de --stdout
From 1d962ecf1e8d42c09abac2f715239a592c9415de Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: "brenohl@br.ibm.com" <brenohl@br.ibm.com>
Date: Wed, 18 Jul 2012 09:29:08 +0000
Subject: [PATCH] cxgb3: Set vlan_feature on net_device

cxgb3 interface has a bad performance when VLAN is set. On my current
setup, a PowerLinux 7R2, I am able to get around 7 Gbps on a TCP_STREAM
(8 instances, 4k message).
With this patch, I am able to reach 9.5 Gbps.

Signed-off-by: Breno Leitao <brenohl@br.ibm.com>
Signed-off-by: David S. Miller <davem@davemloft.net>
---
 drivers/net/ethernet/chelsio/cxgb3/cxgb3_main.c | 4 ++++
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
diff --git a/drivers/net/ethernet/chelsio/cxgb3/cxgb3_main.c b/drivers/net/ethernet/chelsio/cxgb3/cxgb3_main.c
 <PATCH ITSELF>
```

I know I can do some awk/grep stuff to fix it, but, I am wondering if there is a tool that do it for me automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can just redirect the output of `git diff`:

```
git diff <revisions> > /tmp/repo.patch
```

You'll probably have to apply it with the `-p1` flag to `patch`:

```
patch -p1 < /tmp/repo.patch
```